# Using multiple ResourceBundles

Tags: java, eclipse, resources

I'm create a game, and at the start i'm asking the user for a 1/2/3 number input to confirm language selection (1 for dutch, 2 for french, 3 for english). I already have 3 properties files as resourcebundles but now i have no idea how to load them into my game. So when the user puts in 1 in my JOptionPane, there should be a method (or something?) that sets "language" to dutch (cuz nr 1 was inserted), or french if 2 was inserted or 3 for english.

And that has to work on several app-classes, startPlayerApp, startWorldMap, etc... In startPlayerApp for example i ask the user to enter his name, after the language selection, so if he picked dutch it should ask "Wat is uw naam?", if he picked english "What is your name?" etc...

For now everything works, but i "hardcoded" it in String in normal dutch, so it's only unilanguage compatible for now, not multilanguage :(

If anyone could help me as soon as possible (preferably even before the end of this week :p) that would be an amazing gesture! It's for a schoolproject :(!!

Answer (score 0):

Name your resource files to reflect the language:

```
myresource.properties
myresource_fr.properties
...
```

Then use the [ResourceBundle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) and let it detect the language and load the appropriate file:

```
ResourceBundle.getBundle("myresource", Locale.getDefault());
```

Finally, to get the message you need, use:

```
Messages.resources.getString(identifier);
```

Note that I am not passing the `_fr` to it, it will be automagically added if it is the case. If the language requested is not available, it will default to plain `myresource.strings`, so you should put an English translation there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Locale` object as per your user's language selection like `Locale("en")` for English.

```
switch (selection) {
  case 1:
    locale = new Locale("nl");
    break;
  case 2:
    locale = new Locale("fr");
    break;
  case 3:
    locale = new Locale("en");
    break;
  default:
  locale = Locale.getDefault();
}
```

Then use `locale` to load the appropriate `.properties` file from your `classpath`.

```
ResourceBundle localizedMessages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", locale);
```

The first argument passed above is called *basename*. For a given locale `xx`, the resource bundle would load the `basename_xx.properties` file. So, create your .properties file and place them in `classpath`.

messages_en.properties

```
askForName=What is your name?
```

messages_nl.properties

```
askForName=Wat is uw naam?
```

*Copy one of these files as messages.properties as well to serve your default locale from there. (You could remove `_xx` file for your default but I recommend keeping it; helps to switch defaults easily.)*

With all this set up asking a user for her name in her language is as easy as

```
localizedMessages.getString("askForName");
```

**Note**: We have simplified the Locale settings a bit. We could specify a country code as well like `Locale("en", "UK")` to cater for differences in the way a language is used in different countries.

Check [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) for more information.

Comment: So in my chooselanguage application i should add this switch-case, then return said value to my domaincontroller (put it inside a method with a return value "language" or sthing) so that i can invoke said methode in my other application-classes??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Better if "choose language" returns the `Locale` itself. Your domain controller can directly use it to load the appropriate bundle. Ideally, you should have another helper component that exposes the localized messages to the domain controller and the rest of the app.

Comment: Very helpfull thanks! So you're saying: create a local variable in my ui class, and my DC can directly invoke it from within that ui-class, so i can use it in other classes :p? i'm sorry i'm no programming whiz ;)